# Which circuits are in Parallel and which are in series?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

I need to figure out the equivalent resistance of the circuit, but I'm unsure as to how I determine which parts of the circuit are in parallel and which are in series.

Comment: Are R5 and R6 in series or parallel?

Comment: Proceed by steps calculating the equivalent resistance of  $R_5$ and $R_6$, then add coconsider in order $R_4$, $R_3$, $R_2$ and then finally $R_1$. There will be a few boring calculations, but you can reach the result.

Answer (score 2):

It is better you first draw a more simple version of the circuit. Try to figure out that the following figure is equivalent to yours (In fact, they are the same)

[image]

I think in this new figure, it is more manifest that which parts of the circuit are in parallel and which are in series. Start with the smallest part of the circuit.